# How to control numbering of chapters and sections in report document and allow them appear in the content list

Tags: sectioning

I am using the documentclass report in preparing a lab report. I do not want that chapters appear as such (Chapter 1, Chapter 2...). If I use 
     `\chapter*{The name of the chapter}`, I get half the way what I need because if I use the        `\section{}` command, then instead of for example 1.1, I get 0.1 which I do not want. If I then use `\section*{}`, then I do not get numbering of the section. In addition to that the sections and subsections are not shown in the table of content. I looked at many answers, but no one could solve my problem.

Can somebody help me ? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You want to see only the chapter titles, without their number?

Comment: I want to see the chapter titles without their numbers, but I need the numbers for the sections, so that they do not start with 0.1, and I want that the section and sunsection numbers appear in the table of content,

Comment: You can do that with `titlesec` and its `titleformat`  command. However, there will remain the headers problem: how will the chapters appear, if they do? Also, probably cross-referencing a chapter will  be a (solvable) problem.